# "He has played cricket with me"

Tags: tense, passive-voice

In the below sentences, I want to understand why the usage of **has** is correct

**Sentences**

1. He has played cricket with me
2. He is played by me

Above sentences are the right ones. I want to understand why the below sentence is incorrect
**Incorrect sentence**

1. He is played cricket with me

Why is **has played** is right and not **is played**?

Also what is right conversion of active voice for the sentence?

I play cricket with him.

Whether the above conversion is right?

Comment: Why do you use the Indian English tag? Are you only looking for explanations following Indian English grammar?

Comment: He is played by me. = I tricked him.

Comment: @EddieKal I added Indian English grammar wrongly. I will remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no connection in meaning between "is played" and "has played"

"Is played" is a passive voice construction.  "He is played by me" is equivalent to "I play him".

In the sentence "I play him", the subject is "I",  the object is "him".

In the sentence "He is played by me"  The grammatical subject "He" means the object of the verb.  The subject is put in the "by me" phrase, and can be omitted.  There is no grammatical object.  A passive verb can never have a grammatical object.

So "He is played cricket" is grammatically incorrect English.  The word "cricket" is placed as a grammatical object, but a passive verb never has a grammatical object.

On the other hand "has played" is an active verb form, and can have a grammatical object.  "He has played cricket" is correct, just like "He plays cricket".

"I play cricket with him" is active.  "Cricket is played by me with him" is passive (but we would never talk that way in natural English)

Comment: Whether "He is played by me" is a passive voice? I couldn't understand that part. Can you please explain that part a little more?

Comment: The passive voice is [be-verb]+[past participle].   "is played" is a verb in the passive voice. So "He is played by me" is the passive voice.